# ESTA validity after a visa denial

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, esta

If I have an ESTA and I apply for visa and the visa is denied, is my ESTA still valid?

Comment: We are assuming that it was a US visa you applied for. Please correct the question if that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 9):

You must reapply for an ESTA. [The DHS's answer to the question "When do I need to reapply for an ESTA?" states](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e4s1)

> #### When do I need to reapply for an ESTA?
>
> A new travel authorization may be required in any of the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - The circumstances underlying the traveler's previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a "yes" or "no" response have changed.

One of the eligibility questions being:

> Have you ever been denied a U.S. visa you applied for with your current or previous passport, or have you ever been refused admission to the United States or withdrawn your application for admission at a U.S. port of entry?

Comment: + Excellent answer

Comment: What if they apply for a visa to a different country? The OP never specifies that the visa is for the US.